# Search for Worksheets with Common Prefix and Move/Save Matching Worksheets to New Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to (1) search for worksheets that have a common prefix to a district name; that is, where the name of the worksheet is like (matches) the first six characters of the district name, then (2) move the matching files out of my master macro workbook file and into a new workbook file that has the same name as the district name.

I have searched for code to help me do this, but so far am coming up short on making this work.  Here is what I have so far, but I'm getting a ***Compile Error: Next without For*** warning.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, of course!

```
Dim DistWS As Worksheet
Dim DistName As String
  DistName = Left(DistrictDSM, 6) & "*"
  For Each DistWS In WBMaster.Sheets
    If DistWS.name Like DistName Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Move
    With WBMaster
      .SaveAs "H:\Accounting\Monthend " & YYYY & "\DSM Files\DSM Master Reports\" & DistrictDSM & ".xlsx"
   Next DistWS
```

Comment: The Next Without For error is misleading... you're seeing that because you have not "ended" your With statement.  Put an End With before the Next and that error will go away.

Comment: Fantastic!  That fixed the original error, but now I'm getting ***Run time error '1004': This extension can not be used with the selected file type.  Change the file extension in the File name text box or select a different file type by changing the Save as type.***  Do I need to something after ".xlsx" to save the workbook as an Excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to define a workbook variable and assign it before you can move the worksheets to it.  Simply using the .Move function will create a new blank workbook, but that won't automatically get assigned to your workbook object.

Also, it looks like you shouldn't save the workbook until after the loop is finished, assuming there will be more than one matching sheet.

This code should get you closer, but you still may have some variables you need to declare... unless they're declared outside your example code:

```
 Dim DistWS As Worksheet
 Dim DistName As String
 Dim wbNew As Workbook

  DistName = Left(DistrictDSM, 6) & "*"

  Set wbNew = Application.Workbooks.Add

  For Each DistWS In wbMaster.Sheets
    If DistWS.Name Like DistName Then Distws.Move wbNew.Worksheets(1)
  Next DistWS

  With wbNew
    .SaveAs "H:\Accounting\Monthend " & YYYY & "\DSM Files\DSM Master Reports\" & DistrictDSM & ".xlsx"
  End With
```

Comment: That did the trick, Steve!  One last thing:  I need to move the worksheets to keep them in sequential order.  Is this correct? `If DistWS.name Like DistName Then DistWS.Move after:=wbNew.Worksheets(1)`?

Comment: That did the trick, Steve!  One last thing:  I needed to move the worksheets to keep them in sequential order.  This seems to work. `If DistWS.name Like DistName Then DistWS.Move After:=Sheets(WBNew.Sheets.Count)`

Comment: that is a good approach: using the After:= parameter with sheets count.  you will end up with one empty sheet at the beginning, which you could remove before saving the file using wbNew.worksheets(1).delete I think.  To avoid the warning message Excel may show when deleting a sheet, you can turn off alerts before the macro, using Application.DisplayAlerts = False.  Be sure to set it to True after you're done

Comment: As it turns out, I will need that sheet at the beginning to create a summary worksheet representing the sum of all the other worksheets in the file.  Again, thanks so much!!!